# How to rotate shape from its center as well as from center of the screen

Tags: java, rotation, affinetransform

I have created Star shape using `drawPolygon()` but I want to rotate it from the center point of the star as well as from center of the screen.

Here is my code to rotate star from its center:

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    AffineTransform origX = g2d.getTransform();
    AffineTransform newX = (AffineTransform) origX.clone();
    newX.rotate(Math.toRadians(angle), x, y + 62);  // Rotate about center of the star
    g2d.setTransform(newX);
    g2d.drawPolygon(starX, starY, 5);
    g2d.dispose();
    g.dispose();
}
```

If i replace:

```
newX.rotate(Math.toRadians(angle), x, y + 62);
```

to

```
newX.rotate(Math.toRadians(angle), this.getWidth() / 2, this.getHeight() / 2);
```

I can able to rotate it from center of the screen.

However, I want to achieve both the effects simultaneously.
**i.e.**: Like the earth which rotate around the sun as well as its own axis.

I have tried creating another `AffineTransform` object but it overwrite the previous one when I set it using `g2d.setTransform(newObj);`

Any suggestions will be extremely helpful.
Thank you.

**Here is my complete code if you want to see**

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;

public class Star extends Applet implements Runnable{
  private int[] starX;
  private int[] starY;
  private Thread mainThread;
  private int x;
  private int y;
  private int angleFromCenterShape;

  @Override
  public void init() {
    this.setSize(800, 480);
    x = 250;
    y = 150;
    angleFromCenterShape = 0;
    starX = new int[5];
    starY = new int[5];
    mainThread = new Thread(this);
    mainThread.start();
    this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
  }

  @Override
  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    AffineTransform origX = g2d.getTransform();
    AffineTransform newX = (AffineTransform) origX.clone();
    newX.rotate(Math.toRadians(angleFromCenterShape), x, y + 65);   //Rotate about center of the star
    g2d.setTransform(newX);
    g2d.setColor(Color.red);
    g2d.fillPolygon(starX, starY, 5);
    g2d.dispose();
    g.dispose();
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    while(true){
        angleFromCenterScreen = (angleFromCenterScreen + 1) % 360; // angle loop from 0 to 36o
        initStar();
        try{
            Thread.sleep(30);
        }catch(Exception e){}
        repaint();
    }
  }

  private void initStar(){
    starX[0] = x;
    starX[1] = x - 50;
    starX[2] = x + 75;
    starX[3] = x - 75;
    starX[4] = x + 50;
    starY[0] = y;
    starY[1] = y + 130;
    starY[2] = y + 50;
    starY[3] = y + 50;
    starY[4] = y + 130;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround for my problem but it is not an exact solution.
However adding another `rotate()` on the same `AffineTransform` object mimic the 2 rotations

### Here is the code

```
@Override
  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    AffineTransform origX = g2d.getTransform();
    AffineTransform newX = (AffineTransform) origX.clone();
    newX.rotate(Math.toRadians(angle), this.getWidth() / 2, this.getHeight() / 2);  // Rotate from the center of screen
    newX.rotate(Math.toRadians(angle), x, y + 65);   // Rotate from the center of the shape
    g2d.setTransform(newX);
    g2d.setColor(Color.red);
    g2d.fillPolygon(starX, starY, 5);
    g2d.dispose();
    g.dispose();
  }
```